# Adding horizontal lines to an R plotly heatmap

Tags: r, plotly, line, heatmap, r-plotly

I'm trying to add horizontal lines to an `R` `plotly` `heatmap` that will be located between several of the `heatmap`'s rows.

Here's an example `data.frame` and a `heatmap`:

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(1)
df <- matrix(rnorm(18), nrow = 6, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(paste0("r",1:6),1:3)) %>%
  reshape2::melt() %>%
  dplyr::rename(row=Var1,col=Var2)
plot_ly(x = df$col, y = df$row,z = df$value,type = "heatmap")
```

Which gives:
[image]

Now suppose I want to add a horizontal line between `"r2"` and `"r3"` that runs across the entire `heatmap`, and a similar one between `"r4"` and `"r5"`.

I don't know what should be the `y` location the corresponds to that.

I am able to get this done if my `df$row`s are `integer/numeric` rather than `character`:

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(1)
df <- matrix(rnorm(18), nrow = 6, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(1:6,1:3)) %>%
  reshape2::melt() %>%
  dplyr::rename(row=Var1,col=Var2)
plot_ly(x = df$col, y = df$row,z = df$value,type = "heatmap") %>%
  add_lines(y = 2.5, x = c(min(df$col)-0.5,max(df$col)+0.5), line = list(color = "black",dash = "dot",size = 5),inherit = FALSE,showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_lines(y = 4.5, x = c(min(df$col)-0.5,max(df$col)+0.5), line = list(color = "black",dash = "dot",size = 5),inherit = FALSE,showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image]

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to place the horizontal lines between rows if the rows of the heatmap are `character`?
2. Is there a more compact way of adding multiple horizontal lines rather than explicitly having to code each one, as in my code above?

Comment: I am pretty sure the answer to the first question is no. If you don't have another factor level in between your tick marks, how do you wanna draw a line at that position?! so, there may be a hacky solution by manipulating the tick marks and groups/y-axis but not a straightforward one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it would be possible to draw lines between two levels of a factor class.

As for your second question, we can use `add_segments`:

```r
library(plotly)

set.seed(1)

df <- matrix(rnorm(18), nrow = 6, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(1:6,1:3)) %>%
  reshape2::melt() %>%
  dplyr::rename(row=Var1,col=Var2)


hdf <- data.frame(y1 = c(2.5, 4.5), 
                  x1 = rep(min(df$col)-0.5, 2), x2 = rep(max(df$col)+0.5, 2))

plot_ly(x = df$col, y = df$row,z = df$value,type = "heatmap") %>%
  add_segments(data =hdf , y=~y1, yend =~y1, x=~x1, xend =~x2,
               line = list(color = "black",dash = "dot",size = 5), 
               inherit = FALSE,showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image]